# javac compilation issue with packages

Tags: java, ant, javac

Given this (`game.Game.java`, `game.Player.java`, `game.io.InputConsole.java`):

```
src  
|_game  
  Game.java  
  Player.java
  |_io
    InputConsole.java
```

I've been trying to compile this project on console with `javac` (trying out various solutions found on SO and the internet) but I keep failing. I also tried using a batch file, but in either case, all I get are "cannot find symbol" errors.
Since almost all answers to related questions suggest to use a build tool like Ant or Maven, I decided to give it a try with Ant (first time). This is what my Ant file looks like:

```
<project default="run" name="Tic_Tac_Toe">
    <target name="run" depends="compile">
        <java classname="game.Main">
            <classpath path="bin" />
        </java>
    </target>
    <target name="compile">
        <javac srcdir="." destdir="bin"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

This is an excerpt of the output:

```
C:\Users\...\src\game\io\InputConsole.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
  public Player getPlayer(Sign sign) {

symbol: class Player
location: class InputConsole
```

PS: It works when I move `InputConsole.java` into the `game` package. So I'm sure the classes themselves are fine. 
I think the problem is either that I'm failing giving the compiler a proper path or my package structure is wrong.

Comment: Do you have correct package declarations in all the files? `package game.io;`, etc. And `import ...` too. And what is that `Sign` class?

Comment: The former I do, the latter I don't. I thought I don't need imports since basically they are in the same package, just that `InputConsole` is in a sub-package. So where would I have to put `import`s?

Comment: There is no hierarchy among packages.You need import in both. For classes in `package game;` you need `import game.io.InputConsole;`. In `package game.io;` you need `import game.*;`.

Comment: Are you doing this with a simple text editor or with an IDE (IntelliJ or Eclipse)? If it is the former, I suggest to start using an IDE, you can get both for free and they are able to highlight any problems.

Comment: @IvoMori I usually program with an IDE (Eclipse), but I wanted to get familiar with these kinds of things

Comment: Also, if you want to do a real project, I suggest to either use Maven or Gradle but not Ant. Actually, learn about Gradle.

Comment: @DzmitryPaulenka and Miserable Variable Thanks, it works now. :-) You can make an answer to the question if you want to.

Comment: @IvoMori Thanks for the suggestions. I've played around with Maven before. This is just a little TicTacToe project, so I think it'll be managable.

Comment: Just wondering about this question of yours. If you usually use an IDE then why not quickly do it in Eclipse and see what the difference is with respect to package and import declarations?

Comment: @DzmitryPaulenka deserves the green check since he spotted the correct issue immediately, but I won't mind an upvote for the comment on (absence of) package hierarchy.

Comment: @IvoMori Well, that's certainly a point you make there. Never really came to me. Well, I guess I learned a lot because of this, so no regrets of having not considered that :-) (I'm off for a while, the next reply may take an hour or two)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import in both. There is no hierarchy among packages and in spite of appearance `game.io` is not a "sub-package" of game, because there is no such thing as a sub-package.

For classes in `package game;` you need `import game.io.InputConsole;`. In package `game.io;` you need `import game.*;`.

Note that `*` is just convenience, it is probably better to import each referenced class individually.